# I wouldn't be able to connect to the Api Rest (made in python Flask Localhost) from my cell phone

Tags: python, android, flutter, api, mobile

Hi how are u? I wanted to know why I wouldn't be able to connect to the Api Rest (made in python Flask Localhost) from my cell phone (I use it as a divice with the cable, I don't use the emulator).
I don't know if maybe something needs to be configured in android. I read somewhere that you have to put it in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

I put it in but it still doesn't work. I have tried using “localHost” “10.0.0.2” “http://127.0.0.1:8000/” but nothing works.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I send you my code

```
class AuthService extends ChangeNotifier{
  final String _baseurl= 'http://10.0.2.2:8000';
  Future<String> login(String email, String password) async{
    final Map<String,dynamic> authData={
    'email':email,
    'password':password,
    // 'returnSecureToken':true
  };

  final url= Uri.http(_baseurl, 'api/auth'
  // {
  // 'key':_apiToken
  // }
  );

  final resp= await http.post(url,body:json.encode(authData));
  final Map<String,dynamic> decodeResp =json.decode(resp.body);
  print(resp);

  return decodeResp[0];

  }
}
```

If you can help me I would really appreciate it, I'm really going crazy trying to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about flask, however:

1. Are both devices on the same network? This may be a stupid question, but sometimes they aren't.
2. Is the IP address you put the actual private IP address? You can do `ip addr` on Linux and `ipconfig` on Windows to get your private IP address.
3. Try "0.0.0.0". In `http.server`, and possibly in Flask, 0.0.0.0 means any connection. You can also view my similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69347231/how-do-i-make-a-python-server-public).

Comment: nothing works, its the same network, not even the private ip with write ifconfig the "wlp3s0" appears but when I try with another device it doesn't connect (which seems strange to me since I remember that before when I made a rest api I could connect through any computer from the same network by putting the private ip in the browser, but in this case it is not possible)

Comment: @EmanuelLemos Your private IP should be something like `10.0.1.1` or `192.168.1.1`, not "wlp3s0". Sorry I can't help much with Flask. There shouldn't be any different between a PC and a phone. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution , in Flask u must be to write the host

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load_dotenv()
    app.run(debug=True,port=8000,host="your Ip")
```